# GLM - exponential form

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, exponential-family

i stumbled upon the following formula in Kevin Murphy's machine learning book:

[image]

I am familiar wiht the following formula for the exponential family:

$$ 1/Z(\theta) h(x) \exp \left( \theta^T \phi(x) \right) $$

How are these formulas linked? any help very welcome

Comment: The symbols, though are all referred as $\theta$, have different meanings, the second which you are familiar is called "natural parameter", while the first is more specific. It is not hard to find the correspondence between them.

Comment: I think Zhanxiong has hit the nail on the head.  Both are parametric  models with parameter $\theta$ .  They represent different models though.